# REST API post using Twilio is not working. 404 error message with resource not found

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I created a twilio account to make voice calls using api rest.

This is my methods:

```
public function llamadaout_get(){
    $sid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $client = new Client($sid, $token);

    $call = $client->calls->create(
        '+34XXXXXXX', // Call this number
        '+34XXXXXXXXXX', // From a valid Twilio number
        array(
          'url' => 'http://xxxxxxxx:3000/api/calltek/twilio/in'
        )
    );
}

public function llamadain_get(){
    $sayMessage = 'Gracias por contactar con xxxxxx. En breves un operario se pondrá en contacto con usted.';

    $twiml = new Twilio\Twiml();
    $twiml->say($sayMessage, array('voice' => 'alice'));
    $twiml->dial("+34XXXXXXXX");


    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo $twiml;
}
```

I have two urls:

http://xxxxxx:3000/api/calltek/twilio/out -> llamadaout_get()
http://xxxxxx:3000/api/calltek/twilio/in -> llamadaout_in()

Twilio sends me this error:

```
An attempt to retrieve content from http://gestios.calltek.es:3000/api/calltek/twilio/in returned the HTTP status code 404
```

But when i access to the url, i recieve this:

```
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">
    Gracias por contactar con xxxxxx. En breves un operario se pondrá en contacto con usted.
    </Say>
    <Dial>+34XXXXXXXX</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Are you working on MyFone app ?

Comment: I just tried to POST to that URL using POSTMan and also got a 404 but it does respond when I make the request using GET. Are you sure you have the route set up to respond to a POST request?

Comment: Oh much thanks. My fault.